# not able to redirect using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect using javascript and I am able to redirect using document.write() otherwise not.

```
document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
setTimeout(redirect_admin(), 5 * 1000);
```

I want to redirect the page without using document .write()
The entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    btnsubmit = $("#btnLogin");

    btnsubmit.click(function () {
        //$("#preloader").show();
        //$("#status").show();
        var uName = $("#userName").val();
        var uPass = $("#pasWord").val();
        var str = -1;
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            async: false,
            url: "Default.aspx/userLogin",
            data: '{"userName":"' + uName + '","userPassword":"' + uPass + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                str1 = response.d;
                //$('#status').delay(300).fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
                //$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
                str = str1;
            },

            failure: function (msg) {
                bootbox.alert("Please contact your administrator");
            }
        });
        redirectUser(str);
    })


    redirectUser = function (str) {
       if(str == 1){}
       ....
       else if(str ==6) {
          document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
            setTimeout(redirect_admin, 5 * 1000);
        }

       function redirect_admin() {
        var nextUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/AdminHome.aspx";
        window.location = nextUrl;
    }
```

Comment: `setTimeout(redirect_admin, 5 * 1000);`

Comment: What relevance does `document.write` have to `setTimeout`?

Comment: not working even after removing () after the function. redirect_admin

Comment: can you please add the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use () next to the function name.

```
setTimeout(redirect_admin, 5 * 1000);
```

Hope it helps:)

Adding to that,
I am not sure in what way document.write is stopping you from getting things working. You can use a modal or ajax-loader or even an alert instead of document.write. If this is what you mean.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the issue in little more detail? Check the updated answer.

Comment: actually when I use document.write() it creates a blank page which I donot want to

Comment: Oh! ok. Don't use document.write() then.
If you want to signify something, use a modal or ajax-loader or ajax-spinner as I said.
Demo : http://cameronbaney.com/tutorials/css3modal
Code : http://cameronbaney.com/2012/07/26/pure-html5css3-responsive-modal-window/

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for me

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#N").click(function () {

   setTimeout(function () {redirect_admin();}, 5000);
            });
        });

function redirect_admin() {

            window.location = "https://www.google.com";
        }
```

Comment: it is also giving the same output

Comment: Still the same problem persists

Comment: are you using it inside the click event?

Comment: I hv posted the entire code you can check it. Basically I am calling a function from the click event.

Comment: @Aditya `setTimeout('redirect_admin()', 5 * 1000);` Try this also

Comment: It is also not working. I cannot get why it's happening.

Comment: Try my answer with out ()

Comment: Sorry but still no benefit

Comment: @Aditya the above edited function is working for me..here "#N" is a button name.. It is going to google.com after 5 seconds..seems your setTimeout is outside the click event..

Comment: As I told you I am calling a function from click event and from that called function I am using setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

**1. Make sure your else condition block executed**

```
else if(str ==6) {
    console.log(str) 
    document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 5 sec.");
    etTimeout(redirect_admin, 5 * 1000);
}
```

**2. in function `redirect_admin` change `window.location` to `window.top.location`  if you in i-frame and want to redirect top frame**

```
function redirect_admin() {
    var nextUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/AdminHome.aspx";
    window.top.location = nextUrl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, at what point is str set to 6. I cannot see that in the OP code, so perhaps this variable is never evaluated to 6.